# C# Winforms TextBox Multiline not working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, cursor, multiline

Why cannot I get a Winforms TextBox to get the correct current line when I scroll up or down to an invisible line.
Is it my error in CalculateUserTextValue(Point location) method or a bug in the control?
Note: if I expand the TextBox to show all text lines, then it works correctly!
I suspect it is in this part of the code:

```
    // current line text
    int char_index = UserTextTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(location);
    int line_index = UserTextTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(char_index);
    if ((line_index >= 0) && (line_index < UserTextTextBox.Lines.Length))
    {
        m_current_text = UserTextTextBox.Lines[line_index].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // all text
        m_current_text = UserTextTextBox.Text;
    }
```

Here is my full code:

```
    private bool m_currenttext = false;
    private bool m_usertext_mode = false;
    private int m_usertext_selection_start = 0;
    private int m_usertext_selection_length = 0;
    private Point m_caret_position = new Point(0,0);
    private bool m_mouse_down = false;

    private void UserTextTextBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_mouse_down = true;
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_mouse_down)
        {
            if (UserTextTextBox.SelectionLength != m_usertext_selection_length)
            {
                m_usertext_selection_length = UserTextTextBox.SelectionLength;
                CalculateUserTextValue(e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_mouse_down = false;
        CalculateUserTextValue(e.Location);

        // backup m_caret_position
        int char_index = UserTextTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        if (char_index >= 0)
        {
            //BUG in GetPositionFromCharIndex when index is final it returns Point(0, 0)
            m_caret_position = UserTextTextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(char_index);
            if ((char_index > 0) && (m_caret_position == new Point(0, 0)))
            {
                // last line so calculate value of all text
                CalculateUserTextValue();
            }
            else
            {
                CalculateUserTextValue(m_caret_position);
            }
        }
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AcceptButton = UserTextValueButton;
        m_usertext_mode = true;
        m_usertext_mode_values_sequence = false;

        CalculateUserTextValue(m_caret_position);
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_usertext_mode = false;
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                UserTextTextBox.SelectAll();
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // suppress annoying beep due to parent not having an AcceptButton
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
            {
                // Find dialog
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
            {
                // Replace dialog
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                UserTextSaveLabel_Click(m_usertext_load_control, null);
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // suppress annoying beep due to parent not having an AcceptButton
            }
            else
            {
                // don't e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
    }
    private void UserTextTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                CalculateUserTextValue(new Point(0, 0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int char_index = UserTextTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
            if (char_index >= 0)
            {
                //??? BUG in GetPositionFromCharIndex when index is final it returns Point(0, 0)
                m_caret_position = UserTextTextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(char_index);
                if ((char_index > 0) && (m_caret_position == new Point(0, 0)))
                {
                    // last line so calculate value of all text
                    CalculateUserTextValue();
                }
                else
                {
                    CalculateUserTextValue(m_caret_position);
                }
            }
        }

        e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // suppress annoying beep due to parent not having an AcceptButton
    }

    private void CalculateUserTextValue(Point location)
    {
        m_usertext_selection_length = UserTextTextBox.SelectionLength;
        m_usertext_selection_start = UserTextTextBox.SelectionStart;

        if (UserTextTextBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            // selected text
            m_current_text = UserTextTextBox.SelectedText;
        }
        else
        {
            // current line text
            int char_index = UserTextTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(location);
            int line_index = UserTextTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(char_index);
            if ((line_index >= 0) && (line_index < UserTextTextBox.Lines.Length))
            {
                m_current_text = UserTextTextBox.Lines[line_index].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // all text
                m_current_text = UserTextTextBox.Text;
            }
        }

        m_current_text = m_current_text.Replace("\r", "");
        m_current_text = m_current_text.Replace("\t", "");
        m_current_text = m_current_text.Replace("_", "");
        m_current_text = m_current_text.Replace("\n ", "\n");
        m_current_text = m_current_text.Replace(" \n", "\n");
        while (m_current_text.Contains("  "))
        {
            m_current_text = m_current_text.Replace("  ", " ");
        }

        m_current_text = m_current_text.Trim();
        DisplayValuesSequence(m_current_text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `GetLineFromCharIndex()` => Physical line within the Control; `.Lines[]` => logical lines

Comment: What is the alternative to Lines[] in this code please?                   m_current_text = UserTextTextBox.Lines[line_index].ToString();

Comment: There's isn't a method for that, those Controls (TextBox and RichTextBox) handle physical lines, not logical lines. The content of the `Lines[]` property is generated with a (very heavy) calculation that considers all line breaks within a text. So you can use `LastIndexOf()` + `IndexOf()` in relation to the current position to find the limiting `\n` chars in the text (no result with `LastIndexOf()`: first line; no result with `IndexOf()`: last line; any other line if both positive) -- Avoid the `Lines[]` property if you have a lot of text

Comment: WordWrap = false so there should be no difference between physical and logical lines. I tried Split() with the same problem. ```             string[] separators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
            string[] lines = UserTextTextBox.Text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if ((line_index >= 0) && (line_index < lines.Length))
            {
                m_current_text = lines[line_index];
            }
```

Comment: The code, as described, goes like this: `int pos1 = Math.Max(UserTextTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf("\n", char_index) + 1, 0); int pos2 = UserTextTextBox.Text.IndexOf("\n", char_index) - 1; pos2 = pos2 < 0 ? UserTextTextBox.TextLength : pos2; string line = UserTextTextBox.Text.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1);`. No matter whether WordWrap is true or false. If the line you get is the *wrong one*, then the Mouse Location you have passed to `GetCharIndexFromPosition()` is wrong -- If it's a RichTextBox, keep in mind that there's no `\r`